# Django: Generating reports

Tags: python, django

I would like to seek guidance in this matter as I am learning how to build websites under django.

I am trying to find a proper library that fits to my reporting needs but so far the one that fits the bill is [report-builder](https://github.com/burke-software/django-report-builder) but the problem I am facing is that it outputs excel and once the file is downloaded it is editable.

Is there a library that:

- In the admin
- Make reports like [report-builder](https://github.com/burke-software/django-report-builder)(also has a preview)
- Output pdf
- The pdf content can be customize(Inserting company logo etc.)

If it does not exist what is the best course I should take to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of possible interest :) https://joshcarllewis.com/articles/generating-pdf-exports-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReportLab is a library that outputs PDF files dynamically using Django views. You can go through [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-pdf/) to learn more about it.I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried reportlab and It's great! Can it, instead of downloading it, opens a new tab and previews it?

Comment: I have only used reportlab for downloading the pdfs. You may refer to resources available. @JuanCarlosAsuncion

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I settled for `easy_pdf` as it was much more practical to what I need though not as dynamic as reportlab, many thanks